# In a year vs in the year: "This is a small town and not much is going on in a year here"

Tags: articles

> This is a small town and not much is going on **in a year** here, except for a few music events and fairs.

Here I'm trying to say that in my town years go by without much happening. I wonder if we can have "the year" or "during the year" in place of the "a year" in that sentence while maintaining the meaning -- which is that of not pointing to any specific year but a general, standard year in my town.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say something like either

> This is a small town, and not much goes on here...

Or

> This is a small town, and there's not much going on here...

Followed by either

> ..., except for a few music events and fairs.

(There's no real need to mention the year)

Or

> ...over the course of the year, except for a few music events and fairs.

Or perhaps

> ..., except for a few music events and fairs over the course of the year.

Looking again at the title question...

> In a year vs in the year -- This is a small town and not much is going on in a year here

I'm also inclined to suggest that instead of "in a year" or "in the year" you might consider "in a typical year" or "in an average year" or "in a normal year," etc.:

> This is a small town, and not much is going on in a typical year here, except for a few music events and fairs.

This has the advantage of changing your original sentence the least.